# can't set navigator to specific folder in ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-file, android-fileprovider

I want to let user pick one file under a specific folder in Android, whether using built-in ui or third-party file managers. However, I have not been able to do so on newer version of android with **`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`**. I read the documentation about needing a DocumentProvider to provide content uri however I am extremely confused by it since there is no "built-in" ones and it seems that according to the documentation the purpose of implementing such of your own is to serve file to others which is not what I want to do here.

before android actually banned the `file://` uri, what I did is to use ACTION_GET_CONTENT and 'file://' uri to work with most of third-party file manager apps. So if somebody know some hacks on supporting that after 7.0 I would appreciate it too.

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFolder/");
intent.setType("text/csv");
DocumentFile file = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(getApplicationContext(), uri);
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, file.getUri());


intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true);
intent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true);


try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

this code will just go to the "Recent" folder instead of the folder I have.

Answer (score 5):

Try it, it worked for me.

```java
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Download");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Note: EXTRA_INITIAL_URI only supports Android 8 and above

Comment: What happens if EXTRA_INITIAL_URI is used on Android 7 or earlier? Will it crash or just not open the proper folder?

Comment: what if I have a subfolder in Download folder? It doesn't work `primary:Download/AnotherFolder`

Comment: @user924 urlencode `primary:Download%2FAnotherFolder`

Comment: Or https://github.com/moeshin/DocumentUtils/blob/3a9e04ea4981fc8ca34955d286f802f4d044ff5a/document/src/main/java/com/moeshin/util/document/DocumentUtils.java#L64-L78

Comment: @AlanNelson Just not open the proper folder